# Schema: Editing a column name of a table using 'rename column'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, schema

I have a table named `project_updates` and I am trying to rename a column in the table from `update` to `updates`. I ran `rails g migration change_table` and then edited the file like so:

```
class ChangeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :project_updates, :update, :updates
  end
end
```

And then I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and nothing happens. I took the console to see the Model `ProjectUpdate` and it still has `update` rather than `updates`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the schema and run the rake command to generate once again. Not really sure why but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `up` and `down` methods of Rails migration.

Edit the migration like this:

```
class ChangeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :project_updates, :update, :updates
  end

  def self.down
    rename_column :project_updates, :updates, :update
  end

end
```

Probably check your Rails version, might be < Rails 3.1

`change` method of migration was introduced from Rails 3.1